# Convert String to Valid JSON with SED

Tags: json, bash, sed

I have some sudo-json / random string returned from an endpoint where there are double-quotes missing, some commas with nothing in between e.g. `, ,`, and some fields with no values. Example:

```
{issuingColo=1, csUserId=0, expirationTimestamp=2022-11-28 15:53:51.754, sessionId=0, isImpersonator=false, loginSession=1737438, identities=urn:thing:123 , urn:thing:456(urn:thing:account:123,234) , urn:li:thing:123 , , keyVersion=6, tokenVersion=9, permissions=, midToken=123, loginTimestamp=2022-11-28 14:53:49.705, isUser=false, memberId=5555}%
```

and I'm trying to change it to valid json to pass it to `jq`. I tried something like:

```bash
sed 's/\b\([\w:.-]*\)\b/"\1"/g'
```

but that didn't seem to do anything. Any help would be appreciated on what I'm missing!

Comment: JSON uses `:` between keys and values. What you have is not "bad JSON" it's "not JSON". I don't know what format that is, but it's definitely not JSON (looks like a auto-generated Java `toString` implementation)

Comment: ...and without a specification for how other (ideally, _all possible_) values are expressed in the input format, it's impossible to build a tested solution that covers any cases other than the single one you have sample input for.

Comment: Speaking to your `sed` code, though -- sed doesn't support PCRE extensions; the regex syntax you use needs to be BRE or (if you're on a system with non-POSIX extensions) ERE. That means no `\w`, no `\b`, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: sed knows about \w \b but not \d (GNU sed)

Comment: @GillesQuenot, are you referring to GNUisms? I'm looking through https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html for any references to `\w` or `\b` and am not seeing anything yet.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sputnick-dev/25a11d9a7cb4e5caa1229e4bd3f40759

Comment: Thanks @knittl, you're right -- I updated the title of the question to better reflect this is not 'invalid json' but a structured string returned from an endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any experience with JSON, but as an exercise in reformatting to fit JSON, I have put together the following logic which does NOT handle nested braces (I'll look at that for he future).  But for the single line you provided, which is very much malformed, I have come up with the following "transformer" script, if that is the format that is being generated by some canned utility that you are using.

The comma on the last line should not be present, being the last element in the "array".  That is the only item which falls short of compliance with JSON standard.

I also believe that your trailing "**%**" is extraneous, but I have left it in with this code.  That is easily reworked.

So, here is the code for what it is worth, as a learning experience:

```
#!/bin/bash

#QUESTION:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74604942/sed-convert-bad-json-to-valid

echo '{issuingColo=1,  csUserId=0,   expirationTimestamp=2022-11-28 15:53:51.754, sessionId=0, isImpersonator=false, loginSession=1737438, identities=urn:thing:123 , urn:thing:456(urn:thing:account:123,234) , urn:li:thing:123 , , keyVersion=6, tokenVersion=9, permissions=, midToken=123, loginTimestamp=2022-11-28 14:53:49.705, isUser=false, memberId=5555}%' |
    sed 's+{+{\n+g' |
    sed 's+}+\n}\n+g' |
    sed 's+\ ,+,+g' |
    sed 's+,,+,+g' |
    sed 's+^[ ]*++g' |
awk 'BEGIN{
    defer=0 ;
}{
    if( index( $0, "=" ) == 0 ){
        print $0 ;
    }else{
        n=split( $0, seg, ", " ) ;
        for( i=1 ; i<=n ; i++ ){
            gsub( /^ *| *$|/, "", seg[i] ) ;
            if( index( seg[i], "=" ) == 0 ){
                if( index( seg[i], "urn:" ) == 1 ){
                    printf(",\"%s\"", seg[i] ) ;
                    defer=1 ;
                }else{
                    printf("\"%s\",\n", seg[i] ) ;
                } ;
            }else{
                if( defer == 1 ){
                    print "]," ;
                    defer=0 ; 
                } ;
                p=index( seg[i], "=" ) ;
                beg=substr( seg[i], 1, p-1 ) ;
                rem=substr( seg[i], p+1 ) ;
                if( index( rem, "urn:" ) == 1 ){
                    printf("\t\"%s\": [\"%s\"", beg, rem ) ;
                    defer=1 ;
                }else{
                    printf("\t\"%s\": \"%s\",\n", beg, rem ) ;
                } ;
            } ;
        } ;
    } ;
}'
```

The output is as follows:

```
{
    "issuingColo": "1",
    "csUserId": "0",
    "expirationTimestamp": "2022-11-28 15:53:51.754",
    "sessionId": "0",
    "isImpersonator": "false",
    "loginSession": "1737438",
    "identities": ["urn:thing:123","urn:thing:456(urn:thing:account:123,234)","urn:li:thing:123"],
    "keyVersion": "6",
    "tokenVersion": "9",
    "permissions": "",
    "midToken": "123",
    "loginTimestamp": "2022-11-28 14:53:49.705",
    "isUser": "false",
    "memberId": "5555",
}
%
```

Comment: This is great, thanks so much Eric! I was hoping it would just be a problem with my SED regex but seems like more complex logic was needed. I'll accept this answer since it produces the desired output. Thanks again.

Comment: I get the following error:
awk: illegal primary in regular expression ^ *| *$| at
 source line number 9
 context is

Comment: That message is triggered by the gsub statement in the code.  It works fine for me so it can only be explained by a syntax error somewhere in your copy/version of the code.  Did you copy+paste directly? or did you manually retype the code? or have you modified the code after copying it?